# C++. Не могу вставить звук в консольное приложение

Tags: c++, аудио

Не могу вставить звук в консольное приложение. Выдаёт ошибку:

> Ошибка    C2664   "MCIERROR mciSendStringW(LPCWSTR,LPWSTR,UINT,HWND)": невозможно преобразовать аргумент 1 из "const char [72]" в "LPCWSTR".

Вот код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "windows.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <mmsystem.h>


using namespace std;
#pragma comment(lib, "winmm.lib")
int menu;
int main()
{
    cout <<"музыка играет..." << endl;
    PlaySound("D:\\Nuclear Epidemic Episode 1 The Fantastic Dream - Base Location.mp3", 
    NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC);
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Функция `PlaySound` по идее работает только с .wav файлами.

Comment: user780670, всё равно не воспроизводится.

Comment: Читайте [документацию](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dd743680(v=vs.85))

Answer (score 0):

Перед кавычкой имени файла поставь L, это преобразует строку в "широкую" строку, что и есть первый аргумент этой функции

Comment: Спасибо! Сейчас проверю. Не воспроизводится

Comment: Происходит звук ошибки и пишет, что файл не найден

Comment: Новая проблема: программа не может найти файл. Куда файл нужно вставить, чтобы программа смогла воспроизвести его?